# Why is my JavaScript API call returning a 400 error?

Tags: javascript, api, http-status-code-400

I have an API call that is receiving the "Failed to load Resource" 400 error. I have tried deleting cookies and cache and using a different browser. I also removed an image when I saw that image size could be the issue. I read about the need for HTTP headers, but did not understand where that would go in my code or what it would look like. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Here is my JS:

```
    const app = document.getElementById('root');

    const container = document.createElement('div');
    container.setAttribute('class', 'container');

    app.appendChild(container);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'https://www.themuse.com/api/public/jobs', true);
    request.onload = function () {

    // Begin accessing JSON data here
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach(job => {
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.setAttribute('class', 'card');

    const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.textContent = job.title;

    const p = document.createElement('p');
    job.description = job.description.substring(0, 300);
    p.textContent = `${job.description}...`;

    container.appendChild(card);
    card.appendChild(h1);
    card.appendChild(p);
      });
    } else {
    const errorMessage = document.createElement('marquee');
    errorMessage.textContent = `Darn, it's not working!`;
    app.appendChild(errorMessage);
       }
         }

    request.send();
```

Comment: The error is `Not a valid argument for 'page'`, is the API being used correctly?

Comment: https://www.themuse.com/developers/api/v2 On the docs for that endpoint it says the page number is required, you will have to send that up for a valid response.

Answer (score 0):

If you try loading https://www.themuse.com/api/public/jobs in a browser you a 400 error along with the following error message:

> {"code": 400, "error": "Not a valid argument for 'page'"}

That page requires you to supply it with a non-null variable called `page` via your `GET` request.

If you load the page as https://www.themuse.com/api/public/jobs?page=1  (eg) instead you can successfully load the data and your problem disappears!

Comment: The addition of /jobs?/page=1 cleared the error! Thanks so much. Now, onto the next error message. :)